# Zeppelin 0.7.2 integration: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Command line can not be null

Tags: ignite, apache-zeppelin

When I ran SQL like `"%ignite.ignitesql select id from Person"` in my notebook, got the above exception, which seemed some mistake in configuration.

BTW, I used Ignite 2.0.

Jdbc configuration followed the official document.

```
name    value 
ignite.addresses    192.18.134.122:47500..47509 
ignite.clientMode   true 
ignite.config.url   
ignite.jdbc.url jdbc:ignite://192.18.134.122:11211/myCache 
ignite.peerClassLoadingEnabled  true
```

Why?

Comment: Can you show the full trace?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using binary release of Zeppelin-0.7.2, right?
This version of Zeppelin is certified with Ignite-1.9.0

So, I think the root cause of your issue is different version of Ignite.

Perhaps, the following links will be helpful:

- [Ignite Interpreter for Apache Zeppelin](https://zeppelin.apache.org/docs/0.7.2/interpreter/ignite.html)
- https://apacheignite-tools.readme.io/docs/apache-zeppelin